# log4net - 3rd-party dll logs in my file

Tags: c#, dll, log4net

I have created a project which uses log4net for logging. Now, I have also loggings from a 3rdparty-dll in my logfile. How can I prevent this that the 3rd-party dll is logging in "my" file?

this is my logging-configuration:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
    <applicationName value="proconact.dataservice" />
    <threshold value="FATAL" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{2} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/proconact/proconact.dataservice.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <threshold value="DEBUG" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{2} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is all in one namespace, you can do something like.

```
<root>
    <level value="OFF" />
</root>

<logger name="MyNameSpace">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

This switches off logging, except for all namespaces starting with MyNameSpace (and that includes all namespaces inside MyNameSpace).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the logger names used by the third party DLL are consistent, you can add a [filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#filters) to your appenders: this will suppress any logging using a logger name starting with `Third.Party.Logger.Namespace`. It does though have to be added to each appender, and can't be added to the `root` element.

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">  
    <loggerToMatch value="Third.Party.Logger.Namespace" />  
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />  
 </filter>  
 …
```